# ui bootstrap tabs border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I want to remove the side and top borders on active ui bootstrap tabs, and make one fad bottom border. The side and top border is not removed. What am I missing?

```
.nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
border: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;}

.nav-tabs > li.active{
border: 0px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #858585;}

<tabset class="nav nav-tabs tabsetnowrap">
    <tab class="nav-pane" ng-repeat="tab in termstabs track by $index" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <tab-heading>{{tab.title}}</tab-heading>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the overruling section.

if you properly want to be sure that it is overruled you should do it like this:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
    border: none !important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

the `!important` tells the css that unless there is another rule that has the `!important` operater that is later defined that the code must always be the one that is shown.